# Angular 7 - Is there a way to store JSESSIONID and send it in every request?

Tags: angular, spring

I'm developing an angular 7 web app with spring back-end, I implemented security, so spring when you login with the right credentials gives a JSESSIONID cookie. If I try to login with postman I recive the cookie and everything works fine, but in angular it seems it doesn't receive the cookie even if the server responds with 200.

My login.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {
    private apiURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080';

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
    ) { }

    login(credentials) {
        let params = new HttpParams()
            .set('username', credentials['username'])
            .set('password', credentials['password'])

        return this.http.post<any>(`${this.apiURL}/login`, credentials, {
            'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            'params': params
        })
    }
}
```

My login method in login.component.ts:

```
login(){
    this.loginService.login(this.credentials).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res)
    })
  }
```

I'm expecting that the web app stores the cookie and send it in every request so the back-end can check if you are actually loggedin

Answer (score 0):

You can send data in the router which is what I would look for. But in my main project the `JWT` info is stored in localStorage:

```
public saveToken(token: string): void {
    window.localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', token);
}
```

I'm curious if there is a better "Angular" way.

I read through this: [Netbasal's article](https://netbasal.com/set-state-object-when-navigating-in-angular-7-2-b87c5b977bb) with you're question in mind but am not sure if it's a solution or just cool.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular way, you can use typescript with an interface name `Storage`. In the login service you can `@Inject` the storage and use it for example:

```
const LOCAL_STORAGES = new InjectionToken<string>('user-session-local-storage');

@Injectable()
export class UserSessions {

    constructor(
        @Inject(LOCAL_STORAGES) private localStorage: Storage,
    ) {
```

In the method to save the session you can call:

```
private setData(resource: string, value: string) {
        if (!value) {
            return;
        }

        return this.localStorage.setItem(resource, value);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The better approach for you to use will be angular [interceptors](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor). Because of this, you don't have to set others header everywhere too. In your case setting withCredentials: true must work for you.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest,HttpHandler,HttpEvent,   
HttpErrorResponse,HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable, throwError } from "rxjs";
import { catchError } from "rxjs/operators";

    @Injectable()
    export class CustomInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

      constructor() {}

      intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
       if (!request.headers.has("Content-Type"))
         {
              request = request.clone({
              setHeaders: {ContentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
              withCredentials: true,
              observe: 'response' as 'response'
               });         
        }

        return next.handle(request );
      }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, I got an error with te observe option:
https://gyazo.com/c88cabb85596a7dc164ceb7df2fdcdc4

Comment: @AFlawlessGuy Could you try with my updated answer?

Comment: Tried, same error, thanks anyway
this is my code: https://gyazo.com/657cf7d3ca888171c74a972de8241b2d

Comment: is your backend API public and live? So that I can also test.

Comment: No, it was local. But one of my coworker already fixed the issue, idk how though.
But it seems the problem was in the back-end, at least I think so.

Comment: @Amir same error here.  Got this error on observable parameter
https://gyazo.com/af52fc0a739226eae92eeb491b3b8e4f